# Batchable query

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I would like to confirm my understanding to this batchable query. So, this query runs on case records that do not equal Status field from this query? Thanks.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Status, Incident_Open_Age__c, BusinessHoursId from Case WHERE Status != \'Closed\' AND Status != \'Escalated to Tier 3\' AND Status != \'Waiting on Customer\' AND Status != \'On Hold\' AND Status != \'Duplicate\' AND Status != \'Suspected Spam/Out of Office Reply\' AND CreatedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:365';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It runs on Case object and will take all the cases created in last 365 days and having status not listed in the query

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated same as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments the query runs on Case object and will take all the cases created in last 365 days and having status not listed in the query.

I would suggest you to check the [SOQL](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) trailhead which will help you to understand the queries